# Using async/await with pre-defined delegate signature

Tags: c#, delegates, async-await

Given code like this:

```
static void A() {
  string input = "abcabcabc";
  string pattern = "a";
  string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, match => Evaluator(match));
} 

static string Evaluator(Match match) {
  return "d";
}
```

Is there any way to use async/await with a delegate like this?

This:

```
static void B() {
  string input = "abcabcabc";
  string pattern = "a";
  string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, async match => await EvaluatorAsync(match));
} 

static async Task<string> EvaluatorAsync(Match match) {
  return "d";
}
```

...doesn't work - the error message is 'The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task'.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what would you expect `Regex.Replace` to do with am asynchronous evaluator?

Comment: Instead of calling `evaluator(match)`, I would like the Replace method to call `await evaluator(match)`.

Comment: I got that, but why would you want that?

Comment: I'm parsing simple expressions in the form `'{Type:Argument}'` so that a method `GetValue(Type, Argument)` is called for each (replacing the original text). Unfortunately, `GetValue` is `async` .

Comment: But why do you think there's any benefit in making only the match evaluator asynchronous?

Answer (score 2):

The third parameter you are passing to `Regex.Replace` must be of type

```
[SerializableAttribute]
public delegate string MatchEvaluator(
    Match match
)
```

you are passing in an `async` delegate whose return type is `Task<string>`. You can do

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, match => EvaluatorAsync(match).Result);
```

but it will block until the result is available which defeats the purpose and also [it can cause a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). As higlighted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25876854/1239433) Regex searches are CPU bound so `async` will not help you there. The best you can do is use `Task.Run` to push the work to a background thread.

Comment: Im agains't recommending bad patterns. Using `Task.Result` may cause a deadlock.

Comment: I agree, I was just showing how to get it to compile. It's pointless to use `async` for `Regex` anyway as it is CPU bound. I updated the answer to mention the deadlock possibility.

Comment: Regex searches are CPU-bound, but the replacement delegate might not be. Though that should be pretty rare.